# VmWare 6.5 SDK, missing STSService.cs during building C# SSO DLL

Tags: c#, vmware

Using VMware-vSphereSDK-6.5.0,

following the [documentation](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/200aaf00-908e-4b91-9b6c-1da68b83ca00/cc2e7ce6-9ecc-4e28-a845-6b5c878354a6/vsphere-web-services-sdk-65-developer-setup-guide.pdf) for Setting Up for Microsoft C# Development, during the stage "Build the C# SSO DLL" and using the script "build.bat" I receive the message
Could Not Find C:\Users\BillGates\Downloads\VMware-vSphereSDK-6.5.0-4571253\SDK\ssoclient\dotnet\cs\samples\lib\STSService.cs.

is STSService.cs generated from other executables? because it is not place in the folder after downloading the SDK zip.